# Adding a line of XML inside the XML snippet next activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a line of XML inside the XML snippet next activity_main.xml so that the text displayed in the text field is the value of the string book which is defined in strings.xml but am some how stuck. Any help will be appreciated

```
<TextView    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”   
android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />
```

Comment: Add  android:text="@string/your_string_name"

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you trying to add more attributes like `android:text="Hellow World"  or android:textColor="#FF0000"`.  In XML, you can only write one attribute in a line.  OR Are you trying to add comments to the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string defined in **strings.xml** as per the standards

```
  <TextView
    android:text="@string/your_string_id" 
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”   
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />
```